# javascript select all CHECKBOX that not hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, typescript

I have several checkboxes in the page. Some have `hidden=true` and the others `hidden=false`.

I already tried using a selector or jQuery to find checkbox that have the `hidden` property.

What I want to achieve is I've got number of

1. hidden checkbox
2. not hidden checkbox
3. checked not hidden checkbox

```js
let checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[hidden=false]');
let checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[hidden=false]:checked');

console.log(checkBoxes.length);
console.log(checkedBoxes.length);
```

Comment: If you're using `hidden="false"`, then that's invalid. The attribute to hide the element is just `hidden`, it has not value. If you set `hidden="false"` ***then the element will be hidden*** as you've set `hidden` on it.

Comment: You need to educate yourself on how boolean attributes work in HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i can do [hidden]="true" . im using typescript

Comment: That's a very important piece of information that should have been in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the negation operator

```js
    
let checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([hidden])');
console.log(checkBoxes)
```

```html
<input hidden /><input  /><input  /><input hidden />
```

if you are using JQuery there is also the `:visible` selector

Comment: well.. works like a charm. thanks dude. i modify your code lil bit so i can use document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:not([hidden])')

Comment: the question was about selecting hidden, you already knew how to get checked